# Select XML element with colon using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm working with the XML data from Apple's RSS Feed Generator and I've come across a small problem. If I want to select an element from the XML document, normally I would just use querySelector or getElementsByTagName. Unfortunately, this doesn't work if I want to select an element that has a colon in it, for example `<im:name>`.

I've tried various things like escaping the colon with backslashes (this works with JQuery), but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you parsing the XML?

Comment: I parse it into a variable using DOMParser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagNameNS

Comment: You need to know how to handle the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was able to do this by using `getElementsByTagName('image')` (so omitting the "im:" part of the element tag). This seems to work in all browsers except Firefox (not sure about Safari, don't have access to that at the moment). In Firefox it seems I have to select it with the namespace included, `getElementsByTagName('im:image')`.