# How to use `querySelector` to select an element whose label has a colon?

Tags: javascript, xml, css-selectors, queryselector

For example, we have this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<media:content></media:content>
</xml>
```

Then, how can I select the node whose label is `foo:bar` using `querySelector` in JavaScript?

A naive approach is like this:

```js
const xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xml xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <media:content></media:content>
  </xml>
`, 'text/xml');
const node = xml.querySelector('media\\:content');
```

However, after this, `node` is `null`.

Maybe related:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=883044
- [Select elements by attributes with ":" (colon)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45110893)
  (this one talks about when there is a colon in id)
- [Select XML element with colon using plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43822902)
  (the answer suggests `getElementsByTagName`, but I want to use `querySelector` to have more flexibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your example. The first line must be the xml declaration.

```js
const xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xml xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <media:content></media:content>
  </xml>
`, 'text/xml');
```

[Support for namespaces is not provided for the document.querySelector function](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#selectors).

You can use the non-namespaced selector to find the `content` element.

```js
const node = xml.querySelector('content');
```